# Kivy : adding Images in FloatLayout after each touch (on_touch_down), but all previous images disappeared

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to plot an image (`Image` object) each time the `on_touch_down` method is triggered. Each image has the same source. This is done inside the `FloatLayout` and the plotting is done by `self.add_widget(theImage)`. I got no error, but can only display one image after each touch (the previous images disappeared after each touch).

But if i write `print(self.children)` inside the `on_touch_down`, we can see that the list is updated at every `touch`.

Why is this? Thanks.

(*The image size is such that the screen can fit 20 images without colliding each other)

The code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
import random

class Screen(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):           
        super().on_touch_down(touch)
        plot = Image(source='bottle.jpg')
        plot.pos_hint['x'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_x
        plot.pos_hint['y'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_y
        self.add_widget(plot)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen()

app = MyApp()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: I see a strange behavior, print `pos_hint['x'], pos_hint['and']` of childrens and you will see that they are all the same.

Comment: @eyllanesc ah, all previous images follow the the most recent one.. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what is observed if a pos_hint is not established when the widget is created, it has the value of an empty dictionary that is a property of the class and not of the object, meaning that if a value is established an object is established to the others objects.

To verify this, the id of pos_hint is printed obtaining the same value:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):           
    super().on_touch_down(touch)
    plot = Image(source='bottle.jpg')
    plot.pos_hint['x'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_x
    plot.pos_hint['y'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_y
    print(id(plot.pos_hint))
    self.add_widget(plot)
```

Output:

```
140252781257784
140252781257784
140252781257784
140252781257784
...
```

So the solution is to pass a new dictionary:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):           
    super().on_touch_down(touch)
    plot = Image(source='bottle.jpg', pos_hint={'x':.0, 'y':.0}) # <-- default value
    plot.pos_hint['x'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_x
    plot.pos_hint['y'] = random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_y
    self.add_widget(plot)
```

Or pass directly the new dictionary:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):           
    super().on_touch_down(touch)
    plot = Image(source='bottle.jpg')
    plot.pos_hint = {'x': random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_x, 'y': random.uniform(0,1) - 0.5*plot.size_hint_y}
    self.add_widget(plot)
```